# Receive multiple send commands using mpi4py

Tags: python, numpy, mpi, mpi4py

How can I modify the following code (adapted from http://materials.jeremybejarano.com/MPIwithPython/pointToPoint.html) so that every `comm.Send` instance is received by `root = 0` and the output printed. At the moment, only the first send command is received.

```
#passRandomDraw.py
import numpy
from mpi4py import MPI
from mpi4py.MPI import ANY_SOURCE
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    randNum = numpy.zeros(1)
    print "Process before receiving random numbers"


else:
    for i in range(0,np.random.randint(1,10),1):
        randNum = numpy.zeros(1)
        randNum = numpy.random.random_sample(1)
        print "Process", rank, "iteration", i, "drew the number", randNum[0]
        comm.Send(randNum, dest=0)


if rank == 0:
   comm.Recv(randNum, ANY_SOURCE)
   print "Process", rank, "received the number", randNum[0]
```

Comment: Just to clarify / confirm. Am I right in assuming you have no chance to know before hand how many messages each rank will be sending, even on the rank itself?

Comment: Ideally I would like to send messages from each rank without having to know how many messages the rank will send. If this isn't possible, it would be possible to calculate within the rank how many messages will be sent, but this would be different for each rank.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not know how many messages you will send, then you have to introduce a message marking the end of messages. You can use this generically by using special tags. To avoid providing a mismatching buffer for the termination message, you can use `probe` checking what kind of message is coming in

```
tag_data = 42
tag_end = 23

if rank == 0:
    randNum = numpy.zeros(1)
    print "Process before receiving random numbers"
else:
    for i in range(0,np.random.randint(1,10),1):
        randNum = numpy.zeros(1)
        randNum = numpy.random.random_sample(1)
        print "Process", rank, "iteration", i, "drew the number", randNum[0]
        comm.Send(randNum, dest=0, tag=tag_data)
    # send the termination message. Using the lower-case interface is simpler
    comm.send(None, dest=0, tag=tag_end)

if rank == 0:
    # For debugging it might be better to use a list of still active procsses
    remaining = comm.Get_size() - 1
    while remaining > 0:
        s = MPI.Status()
        comm.Probe(status=s)
        # make sure we post the right kind of message
        if s.tag == tag_data:
            comm.Recv(randNum, s.source, tag=tag_data)
            print "Process ", s.source, " received the number", randNum[0]
        elif s.tag == tag_end:
            # don't need the result here
            print "Process ", rank, " is done"
            comm.recv(source=s.source, tag=tag_end)
            remaining -= 1
```

There are many variations of this. For example, if you know that a message is the last message you can merge the termination message.

Comment: At the moment this fails for me at the line `comm.probe(status=s)` with the error `comm.probe(status=s) AttributeError: 'mpi4py.MPI.Intracomm' object has no attribute 'probe'`. Also, is there a signifcance to the tag numbers you chose, or is it just necessary to identify `tag_end` separately to `tag_data` and any number would do? Or are certain numbers reserved for particular processes?

Comment: Maybe `probe` was introduced in version 2.0.0 of mpi4py. Just substitute with the upper-case `Probe`, should make no difference. The tag values are completely arbitrary, they just need to be distinct. The actual values in my examples are references to [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29#Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) and [23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/23_%28film%29), even though I haven't actually seen the latter.

Comment: It seems `comm.probe` did only come in mpi4py version 2.0.0. I have a `python3` install using this and the original code you posted works (obviously with modified `print` statements). However, with the older version of mpi4py `comm.Probe` causes the process to hang. Also in the line `print "Process ", rank, " is done"` this always prints `rank=0`. Presumably replacing `rank` with `s.source` will print the `rank` that has just terminated and sent `tag_end`?

Comment: Not sure why it would hang in an older version? Do you know where it hangs, or you can just use a current version of `mpi4py`? Yes, `rank` should have been `s.source`. I fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If each process knows the number of messages to be sent, the following steps can be designed to solve the problem:

1) Reduce the number of message to be sent to root process. Each process sends to the root the number of messages it will later send. This operation is called a reduction and it can be performed by the function `comm.reduce(...)`

2) Receive all the messages on process 0.

Here is a code based on yours that should do the trick. It can be ran by `mpirun -np 4 python main.py`

```
#passRandomDraw.py
import numpy
from mpi4py import MPI
from mpi4py.MPI import ANY_SOURCE
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

#just in case, if numpy.random is seed with 
np.random.seed(np.random.randint(np.iinfo(np.uint32).min,np.iinfo(np.uint32).max)+rank)

if rank == 0:
    randNum = numpy.zeros(1)
    print "Process before receiving random numbers"
    nb=np.empty((1,),dtype=int)
    nb0=np.zeros((1,),dtype=int)
    comm.Reduce([nb0, MPI.INT],[nb, MPI.INT],op=MPI.SUM, root=0)  #sums the total number of random number from every process on rank 0, in nb.
    #print "rank"+str(rank)+" nb "+str(nb)
else:
    nb=np.empty((1,),dtype=int)
    nb[0]=np.random.randint(1,10)
    #print "rank"+str(rank)+" nb "+str(nb)
    comm.Reduce([nb, MPI.INT],None,op=MPI.SUM, root=0)
    for i in range(0,nb[0],1):
        randNum = numpy.zeros(1)
        randNum = numpy.random.random_sample(1)
        print "Process", rank, "iteration", i, "drew the number", randNum[0]
        comm.Send(randNum, dest=0)



if rank == 0:
   for i in range(nb[0]): #receives nb message, each one with its int.
       comm.Recv(randNum, ANY_SOURCE)
       print "Process", rank, "received the number", randNum[0]
```

According to the [documentation of `numpy.random()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState) the Mersenne Twister pseudo-random number generator is initially seeded by a number extracted from `/dev/urandom` (or the Windows analogue) if available or seed from the clock otherwise. Hence, in the last case, all processes can receive the same seed and generate the same random numbers. To prevent this from happening, I added the following line:

```
np.random.seed(np.random.randint(np.iinfo(np.uint32).min,np.iinfo(np.uint32).max)+rank)
```