# MPI + tqdm - updating progressbar from one process only

Tags: python, mpi4py, tqdm

I have a script which is set up to run with `mpiexec` with multiple processes at the same time. I'm using `mpi4py` to manage the MPI stuff from python. I also really like `tqdm` for progress bars. The problem is that the multiple processes can break `tqdm` in all sorts of ways because multiple instances print to the same screen.

Is there a way to tell `tqdm` to only print updates on some condition? I'm looking for something like the following:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
from tqdm import trange
from time import sleep

t = trange(10)
for i in t:
    sleep(0.5)
    if MPI.COMM_WORLD.rank == 0:
        t.update_progress()  # <--- Not working, but I want this.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are probably looking for something in the lines of:

```
pbar = tqdm.tqdm(total = len(inputs))
for i in t:
    if something_with_i:
         pbar.update(1)
```

Comment: The pbar won't be inhered in the subprocess in mpi4py.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/36094541/9217178

I put my 2 cents:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from mpi4py import MPI

communicator = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = communicator.Get_rank()
nb_process = communicator.Get_size()
total = 100
compute_tag = 0
end_tag = 99

if rank == 0:
    # rank 0 is the master node to update progress bar
    pbar = tqdm(total=total)
    update_msg = None

else:
    update_msg = None

#******************************************************************* I'm a Barrier
communicator.Barrier()
if rank == 0:

    remaining = nb_process - 1
    while remaining > 0:
        s = MPI.Status()
        communicator.Probe(status=s)
        if s.tag == compute_tag:
            update_msg = communicator.recv(tag=compute_tag)  
            #note: send/recv for basic python instances and Send/Recv for numpy array

            # only master to update pbar
            pbar.update(1)
        elif s.tag == end_tag:
            update_msg = communicator.recv(tag=end_tag)

            # remaining drops to 0, loop ends
            remaining -= -1
            print('remaining: {}', remaining)

else:
    for i in range(10):
        #compute something and send a message to master node (rank 0)
        communicator.send(update_msg, dest=0, tag=compute_tag)

    # when this node ends send a eng_tag message
    communicator.send(update_msg, tag=end_tag)
```